# Debugging .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, debugging

A few days ago I had a problem with writing my first htaccess in order to remove .html extension from URL. There were problems because I had a Windows server which I changed to Linux.

Now the issue is this:
I finally did manage to remove the .html extension from URL. What I can't do is to set an expiration date for all images (JPEG, PNG, SVG).

My working code is this (extension removal):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

For Image caching parameter I added the following:

```
//Caching schema
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|svg)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private, max-age=160704000"
</FilesMatch>
```

When I added the additional code above I got an internal server error.
I don't know what's going on to be honest. If I remove this additional code it will work but if I add this then it wont.

So do you guys have any ideas of how to add an Image caching parameter?? The additional code above doesn't work :(

Comment: I used http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it says that "{REQUEST_FILENAME})" it's not supported so it's not that important. The actual problem is in the image caching parameter.

Comment: `//Caching schema` is wrong as `//` is not considered a comment. Use `#Caching schema`. Also `htaccess.madewithlove.be` is not the right place to test htaccess, test it on your local webserver.

Comment: `htaccess.madewithlove.be` doesn't support `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`, you can see message about this at the bottom of this web-site.

Comment: One should always check Apache error.log for internal server error

Comment: Thank I noticed that. In fact the only thing that it's not working and it give me an internal server error is the code for the image. Any ideas?

Comment: There must be more info than 'internal server error'. What does the relevant error_log say.

Comment: I think I did it :) :) .. thank you all. Quick question.. When testing my page in dtmetrix.com I got a suggestion to add "Vary: Accept-Encoding" ... Should I go for it? is this something of an important  thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**
After some research I tried this one:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
ExpiresActive On

# Expires after 1 month
<filesMatch ".(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|pdf|js|htm|html|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</filesMatch>

# Expires after 1 day
<filesMatch ".(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

Surprisingly this works. I tested it with gtmetrix.com .You think I should move forward now?

Comment: Are the headers being set correctly? That would be surprising as the manual does not mention a dependency between mod_headers and mod_expires, but if it works then yes move forward.

Comment: yes.. it does work :) :) thanks for your input and your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

Set `AllowOverride All` in your server config for the host. Do this for the directory where your htaccess resides rather than the whole server, e.g.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/mysite/>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The issue is that your syntax is valid, but the server is refusing to process the request because AllowOverride is set to something other than 'All' which is what FilesMatch requires.

If you don't want to set AllowOverride to All for the .htaccess file, then you could move the `<FilesMatch>` statement into the host configuration for your site and it will work from there.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Really appreciated.